# Можно ли добавить на кастомную страницу админки кусок редактора страниц (или страницу редактора целиком)?

Tags: wordpress, админка

Возник такой вопрос: у меня есть кастомная страница в админке (я ее создал в виде плагина, все ок). т.к. своего контента у этого плагина нет, то через WP_Query впаял туда отображение контента обычной страницы (типа page), которую сделал приватной и на пользовательской стороне не показываю. Однако никакие мои попытки на отдельную вкладку (div) этой страницы поместить кусок редактора страниц (в целом мне нужна только часть с визуальным редактором) - не увенчались успехом.

Пробовал добавить на свою страницу редактор стандартными средствами - все ок, он появляется, но в нем никак нельзя отредактировать страницу и запись, для этого нужно переходить в соответствующие редакторы в админке.

WP_Screen - тоже не про то...

Можно ли так сделать в принципе? И как это делается?

Comment: Речь про страницу настройки плагина (добавляется как add_options_page() или как вариант add_theme_page() ). Есть ли способ затащить на такую страницу элементы управления другим плагином, посттайпом или таксономией?

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли так сделать в принципе? И как это делается?

Это делается созданием произвольных типов контента, а не какой-то непонятно сделанной "страницей в админке". 
Если не надо выводить посты на фронт, то при создании это указывается в параметре  `public`

См
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type

Comment: Никак нет! Посттайпы служат для создания собственных типов страниц и получают свой собственный пункт в меню (опционально) с  редактором контента (можно настроить какие блоки в нем будут и т.д.) - это все мне известно и этим я прекрасно пользуюсь.

Comment: У меня вопрос скорее про страницу настройки плагина (добавляется как add_options_page() или как вариант add_theme_page() ), которая по умолчанию является кастомной и не содержит никаких элементов вообще. Есть ли способ затащить на эту страницу элементы управления  другим плагином, посттайпом или таксономией?